# Add MonoTouch.Dialog on PopOverView

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm trying to add an dialog to an `CustomPopoverViewController` ([see picture](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2230967/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%20Feb%208,%202012%2011.33.23%20PM.png)) but I can't add it to the view. I have tried different methods but it will not display.

```
[Register("MyCustomPopoverViewController")]
public partial class MyCustomPopoverViewController : UIViewController
{
    DetailViewController appd;

    public MyCustomPopoverViewController (DetailViewController app)
    {
        appd = app;
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Paged view did load");
        this.ContentSizeForViewInPopover = new SizeF (370, 670);

        var root = new RootElement ("Meals"){
        new Section ("Dinner"){
                new RootElement ("Desert", new RadioGroup ("desert", 2)){
                    new Section (){
                    new RadioElement ("Ice Cream", "desert"),
                    new RadioElement ("Ice Cream", "desert"),
                    new RadioElement ("Ice Cream", "desert"),
                    new RadioElement ("Ice Cream", "desert"),
                    new RadioElement ("Ice Cream", "desert")
                    }
                }
            }       
        };
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer my self. The solution is like this:

```
        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Paged view did load");
        this.ContentSizeForViewInPopover = new SizeF (370, 670);

        var root = new RootElement ("Meals"){
        new Section ("Dinner"){
                new RootElement ("Desert", new RadioGroup ("desert", 2)){
                    new Section (){
                    new RadioElement ("Ice Cream", "desert"),
                    new RadioElement ("Ice Cream", "desert"),
                    new RadioElement ("Ice Cream", "desert"),
                    new RadioElement ("Ice Cream", "desert"),
                    new RadioElement ("Ice Cream", "desert")
                    }
                }
            }       
        };
                    // This is the solution!
        var dv = new DialogViewController (root);
        View.Add(dv.View);
    }
```

Comment: You can mark your question as answered (green mark below the votes) so other people will see an answer is available when doing a search on similar keywords (it's ok the answer your own question on stackoverflow, see FAQ).